# Javascript Module and Scope

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript module patterns for the first time, as my scripting is starting to look messy and unmanageable the bigger my project gets.

Using the following example I just built, how can I get access to the 'elements' I've set? In the bottom function **makeCoverBigger**, I'm trying to manipulate an element `$('.coverCar')` by using `el.coverCar` but I'm not able to do so.

I'm not getting any bugs, it just won't play ball. I've tried using `this.el.coverCar` also. I'm assuming it's a scope issue with `el` or I'm missing something? If I replace `el.coverCar` with `$('.coverCar')` it works fine.

```
<script>
var CoverCarWidget = (function() {
    var el;
    return {
        elements: {
            coverCar: $('.coverCar'),
            coverCarFilter: $('.coverCarOverlayPattern'),
            coverCarScrollBtn: $('.coverCarScroll')
        },
        init: function() {
            el = this.elements;
            this.makeCoverBigger();
        },
        makeCoverBigger: function() {
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            if (el.coverCar.is(':visible')) el.coverCar.height(windowHeight+'px');
            console.log("This fires okay");
        }
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    CoverCarWidget.init();
});
</script>
```

**THE PROBLEM - NOW FIXED**

At the time the CoverCarWidget was constructed, the DOM was not ready, and so the element object was essentially empty. Setting those elements at DOM ready/init() fixes this problem. Please see the accepted answer for details.

Comment: `el` is a variable with no value assigned to it. `el.covercar` is JavaScript object syntax but `el` is not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, your `CoverCarWidget.elements` variable is just a normal object, which gets initialized as CoverCarWidget is created. This means `coverCar` gets assigned before the document ready event fired.

When you make `elements` a function, the jQuery selectors inside will be executed on document ready and will find elements.

```
var CoverCarWidget = (function() {
    var el;
    return {
        getElements: function () {
            return {
                coverCar: $('.coverCar'),
                coverCarFilter: $('.coverCarOverlayPattern'),
                coverCarScrollBtn: $('.coverCarScroll')
            };
        },
        init: function() {
            el = this.getElements();
            this.makeCoverBigger();
        },
        makeCoverBigger: function() {
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            if (el.coverCar.is(':visible')) el.coverCar.height(windowHeight+'px');
            console.log("This fires okay");
        }
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    CoverCarWidget.init();
});
```

- When your code worked in JSFiddle before it's just because JSFiddle execute your whole JavaScript code in the onLoad event of the page by default.
- By the way: your code did not produce errors, because jQuery always returns a proper object and silently does nothing, if no elements matched your selector.

Comment: Thanks, Jan. It now makes sense why my elements weren't accessible - because they weren't available at the time of build! You were the only one to actually notice that, so well done.

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
var wrapper = (function() {
    var private;
    return object;
})();
```

`wrapper` becomes the returned object.

In your case, to access `elements`, you can use `CoverCarWidget.elements`, because `elements` is a property of the returned object, which is assigned to `CoverCarWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `var el;`, everything is already available to you.

```
var CoverCarWidget = (function() {
    return {
        elements: {},
        init: function() {
            this.elements = {
                coverCar: $('.coverCar'),
                coverCarFilter: $('.coverCarOverlayPattern'),
                coverCarScrollBtn: $('.coverCarScroll')
            };
            this.makeCoverBigger();
        },
        makeCoverBigger: function() {
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();
            if (this.elements.coverCar.is(':visible')) this.elements.coverCar.height(windowHeight+'px');
            console.log("This fires okay");
        }
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    CoverCarWidget.init();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jb5mt/2/

You also don't really need an init method.

Comment: I removed a ton of `init()` functions from this module to make the question simpler and more readable. This isn't by any means the entire module. Do you still suggest not having an init method?

Comment: if you need it, you need it. in the sample you provided you don't need it.

Comment: Just a note though, the real problem with your code is the way the elements object is initialized, touched on by Jan's answer. this answer just gets rid of an unneeded global-ish var. Initializing your `elements` object inside the `init` method would be a good way of fixing the problem. I'll update with a sample. (done)

Comment: Yes, I think Jan has the answer. No matter what I try, those elements were just not accessible. It makes sense that the object was built before the DOM was ready, hence no element. Thanks for your input also, Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use **revealing module pattern**, but maybe I am mistaken. Using revealing module pattern your code would look like this:

```
<script>
var CoverCarWidget = (function() {
    var elements: {
        coverCar: $('.coverCar'),
        coverCarFilter: $('.coverCarOverlayPattern'),
        coverCarScrollBtn: $('.coverCarScroll')
    };

    function makeCoverBigger(){
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        if (elements.coverCar.is(':visible')) elements.coverCar.height(windowHeight+'px');
            console.log("This fires okay");
    }

    // here you return object literal with the methods that you want to expose.
    return {
        elements: elements,
        init: function() {
            makeCoverBigger();
        },
        makeCoverBigger: makeCoverBigger
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    CoverCarWidget.init();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable in the Revealing Module Pattern to expose your functions/variables in the `return` as the OP did above, rather than creating the function and then exposing the function through an object property of the same name. As far as I know, there's no downsides to the way you have it here. Just a little extra coding.

Comment: If you look at my example, you'll see that I do understand that -> Init function. I moved over makerCoverBigger so it is easier to access defined elements, and you don't need to care about "this" context.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to your parent object. The typical convention is to use `var self = this;`

```
var CoverCarWidget = (function() {
        var el;
        var self = this;
        return {
            elements: {
                coverCar: $('.coverCar'),
                coverCarFilter: $('.coverCarOverlayPattern'),
                coverCarScrollBtn: $('.coverCarScroll')
            },
            init: function() {
                el = self.elements;
                this.makeCoverBigger();
            },
            makeCoverBigger: function() {
                var windowHeight = $(window).height();
                if (el.coverCar.is(':visible')) el.coverCar.height(windowHeight+'px');
                console.log("This fires okay");
            }
        };
    })();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        CoverCarWidget.init();
    });
```